# why expo-file-system downloadAsync, is so slow?

Tags: react-native, download, youtube, expo

when i download some youtube video by https://rr2---sn-jxaaoxupn2p9-pn0e.googlevideo.com/ the process take time to download it while my internet connection is fast..
here is my code:

```
     let download = FileSystem.downloadAsync(link, songuri).then(
          (uri) => {
            db.transaction(async (tx) => {
              tx.executeSql(
                "UPDATE lib13 SET dl = 't' WHERE idsong = '" +
                  song.id.toString() +
                  "' ;"
              );

              alert("Downloaded Successfully Enjoy :)");
              dispatch(setadd(!relvl.add));
            });
            setdl("d");
          }
        ); //song downloaded
```

Comment: Did you find out something?

Comment: i just realize the file is corrupted and also change extension of file such as mp4 to ma it's cause to slow download...